# convert data in to ToList()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have One table named Company 
in this i am trying to access the data of that table using linq  Query and converted into company Calss like

```
List<Company> companyData = (from c in dataContext.Companies 
       select new 
       {
           CompanyName =c.CompanyName,
           Address1 =c.Address1,
           Addredd2 =c.Address2,
           city=c.City.CityName,
           state =c.State.StateName,
           country =c.Country.CountryName,
           Telephone1 =c.Telephone1,
           Telephone2 =c.Telephone2,
           Mobile1 =c.Mobile1,
           Mobile2=c.Mobile2,
           Email1 =c.Email1,
           Email2 = c.Mobile2,
           Fax1=c.Fax1,
           Fax2=c.Fax2,
           TinNo=c.TinNo,
           IsGroupCompany=c.IsGroupCompany 
       }).ToList<Company>();
```

but it gives error like ToList() have some invalid argument 
how can in give the columnname get data in List format

Thaks in Advance

Comment: What table? Do you mean "DataTable" class?

Comment: As others point out, the real key is to make sure that you explicitly code `select new Company {}` for this to work.

Comment: Yes but again another aim is to give different column names after new selection and still make it Company type. I think that wont be possible.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for this:

```
List<Company> companyData = (from c in dataContext.Companies select new Company {
  CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
  Address1 = c.Address1,
  Address2 = c.Address2,
  City = c.City,
  State = c.State,
  Country = c.Country,
  Telephone1 = c.Telephone1,
  Telephone2 = c.Telephone2,
  Mobile1 = c.Mobile1,
  Mobile2 = c.Mobile2,
  Email1 = c.Email1,
  Email2 = c.Email2,
  Fax1 = c.Fax1,
  Fax2 = c.Fax2,
  TinNo = c.TinNo,
  IsGroupCompany = c.IsGroupCompany }
  ).ToList();
```

In other words, your code is instantiating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), but you are trying to create a list of Company objects.  Therefore, instantiate a Company object instead.

Chances are, however, that you don't need to create a set of new Company objects with their properties copied from each of another set of Company objects.  If that's true, you can just do this:

```
List<Company> companyData = dataContext.Companies.ToList();
```

If you need to name the properties differently, then you are correct to use an anonymous type.  In that case, you must use the `var` keyword, since the objects are no longer instances of the `Company` class:

```
 var companyData = (from c in dataContext.Companies   
   select new   
   {  
       CompanyName =c.CompanyName,  
       Address1 =c.Address1,  
       Addredd2 =c.Address2,  
       city=c.City.CityName,  
       state =c.State.StateName,  
       country =c.Country.CountryName,  
       Telephone1 =c.Telephone1,  
       Telephone2 =c.Telephone2,  
       Mobile1 =c.Mobile1,  
       Mobile2=c.Mobile2,  
       Email1 =c.Email1,  
       Email2 = c.Mobile2,  
       Fax1=c.Fax1,  
       Fax2=c.Fax2,  
       TinNo=c.TinNo,  
       IsGroupCompany=c.IsGroupCompany   
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: I think that wont work if for example he assigns `NewCompany=c.CompanyName`. It must have same name as in database. Any solution to give different column names ?

Comment: In this Query i have to give same name of column of table field when give different name to the column it generate error

Comment: Yes thats wat I asked.. Any suggestions for that ?

Comment: @vipul I don't understand your question entirely (it would help if you used some punctuation in your sentences).  I have added an example to show how to use an anonymous type, if that's what you need.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Marshal look again; he actually assigns `CompanyName =c.CompanyName` as part of the anonymous object initialization expression `new {   CompanyName =c.CompanyName, ...`

Comment: @phoog:What he actually wants is to create a new anonymous type, for giving new Column names and then again convert this anonymous type to Company. Bu then I think that wont be possible.

Comment: @Marshal it would be possible to convert the anonymous objects to Company objects using another query: `anonList.Select(a => new Company { CompanyName = a.CompanyName, ... })`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Company> companyData = (from c in dataContext.Companies 
           select new Company() { ... }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to DataTable, then you can do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("address", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add("name 1", "address 1");
        table.Rows.Add("name 1", "address 1");

        var query = table.AsEnumerable().Select(s => new Company { Name = (string)s["name"], Address = (string)s["address"] }).ToList();
    }
}

class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this :-
List<Company> companyData = (from c in dataContext.Companies 
select new Company
{
       CompanyName =c.CompanyName,
       Address1 =c.Address1,
       Addredd2 =c.Address2,
       city=c.City.CityName,
       state =c.State.StateName,
       country =c.Country.CountryName,
       Telephone1 =c.Telephone1,
       Telephone2 =c.Telephone2,
       Mobile1 =c.Mobile1,
       Mobile2=c.Mobile2,
       Email1 =c.Email1,
       Email2 = c.Mobile2,
       Fax1=c.Fax1,
       Fax2=c.Fax2,
       TinNo=c.TinNo,
       IsGroupCompany=c.IsGroupCompany 
   }).ToList();
```